# hibernate3 calendar_date adds time with jdk 1.8

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic9.x

When we upgraded from weblogic 9c(JDK 1.5) to weblogic 12c(JDK 1.8), hibernate type calendar_date is adding time to the field. Except weblogic version nothing else has changed. In weblogic 9c the same column is getting populated with only Date(with out time), but in weblogic 12c column is getting populated with Date along with Time. Could some one guide me in right direction?

```
<property name="hireDate" column="hire_date" type="calendar_date"/>
```

**weblogic 9c**

```
hire_date = 05/15/2017
```

**weblogic 12c**

```
hire_date = 05/15/2017 08:22:36
```

Comment: calendar_date type is deprecated. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#CALENDAR_DATE

Comment: But why does it behave differently with JDK 1.8?